# Create Index lookup that takes duplicates into account

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dummy dataset in excel which looks like this.

[image]

For convenience assume that this range is pasted from cell A1 to B7 in a worksheet.

I want to create a range that shows me the top 5 highest Counts by ID. Hence the end product should look like:

[image]

To accomplish this I have used an index formula together with a match function containing a Large function that gives me which the K largest value is. So for example for the top 1 result in the ID column below I use:

`=INDEX($A$2:$B$7,MATCH(LARGE($B$2:$B$7,1),$B$2:$B$7,0),1)`

Similarly for the top 1 result in the Count column below I use

```
LARGE($B$2:$B$7,1)
```

If I apply this to all my cells, changing the value of K per row, I get a final result looking like:

[image]

As you can see the result works well for ID's that do not have the same Count. However on those where the Count is the same, I get duplicates. Hence what I am looking for is a function that looks if it is about to output a duplicate and then instead look if there is another ID with the same Count value.

I believe this may be challenging in base Excel but perhaps there is a way to do it in VBA? However I am not very familiar with VBA and I can't seem to find anything on the internet around this. Would anyone have a clue how to go about this?

Many thanks!

Comment: This can easily be done in vanilla Excel with a pivot table and a custom top filter -- not even any formulas required.

Comment: Yes I can see how that might look like a solution given the dummy sample code I posted. But in reality I have a very large Pivot with ID and Dates as a group and count as an aggregate together with many other aggregates. Hence it is a bit more complex and can't be done with filtering.

Comment: It's possible to create a pivot table using a pivot table as the source (i.e. not modifying the first one). I do agree that can get complicated, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link your ID output to that of the Count Ouput, using COUNTIF() to return the correct k.

```
=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($A$2:$A$7)/($B$2:$B$7=F2),COUNTIF($F$2:F2,F2)))
```

[image]